# how to export neo4j data of database A to database B?

Tags: neo4j

I have two cases:
 case 1:export a part of data in neo4j database A to database B,like data of Label "Person" in database A ,I wanna export "Person" data from A to B

case 2: export whole data from A to B

so how to deal with these two cases? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APOC allows to export the full graph or subgraphs into a cypher file consisting of create statements, see https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_export_to_cypher_script for details.

The other option would be access the other database via the [neo4j jdbc driver](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc) and use `apoc.load.jdbc` to retrieve data from there.